# Is there a parent child relationship between absolute and relative positioning in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am new to the world of coding as well as CSS. Having read a number of articles regarding `relative` and `absolute` positioning, my understanding is as follows. However, I am unsure if an `absolute` position should be the child of a parent `relative` position or vice versa.

- There are 4 position properties, that is, `static, relative, absolute and fixed`.
- If an element has a `relative` position it is still part of the normal flow of the document. However, it has the ability to be offset by the properties `top, right, bottom and left`.
- It also is able to be given a `z-index` value and is automatically positioned above static elements
- It also provides a method of containing child elements that are part of its code block although I am unsure exactly what this means.

Based on this information, does this mean that elements with the position `absolute` should be children of elements with the position `relative` or vice versa or does it not matter?

If it does not matter, when would you make them dependent upon one another e.g. parent-child relationship?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is not really a parent-child relationship.

Relative positioning has nothing to do with absolute positioning. Relative positioning is the same as normal static positioning except that it can be offset top/right/bottom/left, as you explain. The "top/right/bottom/left" values are relative to wherever the element would normally exist in the flow. If you leave out these values, the element is still relatively positioned but it is positioned exactly as if it were statically positioned.

OTOH, when you use absolute positioning, "parent" elements of the absolutely positioned element do matter.

This is because of what LaC's answer explains. With absolute positioning, the "top/right/bottom/left" values are relative to whatever is the nearest parent element to have absolute, relative or fixed positioning. I'll call this the "reference element."

Consider this example fragment:

```
<body>
  <div style="width: 50%;">
    <p style="position: absolute; width: 20px; top: 0; right: 0">P</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

The div will be left-aligned, static (normal, in the document flow) position, 50% the width of the body. The p will be a 20px-wide box, in the top-right corner of the viewport:

```
-------------
|     |   |P|
|     |   --|
| div |     |
|     |     |
|     |     |
-------------
```

The viewport is the reference element because there are no other parent elements of the p that have absolute/fixed/relative positioning.

Now change the div to be relatively positioned:

```
<body>
  <div style="position: relative; width: 50%;">
    <p style="position: absolute; width: 20px; top: 0; right: 0">P</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

The div will appear exactly the same as before, because no top/right/bottom/left offset has been specified. However, the position of the p will change, even though its style hasn't.

That is because, before, the p was aligned to the top-right corner of the viewport, but now there is a closer parent element (the div) with absolute/fixed/relative positioning. So now, the div becomes the reference element and the p will be aligned to its top-right corner:

```
-------------
|   |P|     |
|   --|     |
| div |     |
|     |     |
|     |     |
-------------
```

So, just know that whenever you use absolute positioning, you have to think about what the reference element in the document will be. And, you can design your stylesheet so that you choose whatever this reference element is, which makes absolute positioning a very useful layout technique.

Comment: There you go PeanutsMonkey. The reason why some people are great teachers. Never could have explained more clearly. Now wait till you have to pronounce "Specifeecity....Specfesety....Spesciphicity...Oh! I give up

Comment: @joelhardi - Thanks. That is a very good example of using relative and absolute positioning. I take it that if I have the body set to have the margin and padding of 0, the viewport would be the body tag. Is that right? If so that would mean any correspoding element e.g. div, p would be relative to the body. Hence the div which is the parent of p, p would be relative to div whilst div would relative to the body. Is that right?

Comment: You're welcome! To answer your question, in my basic example yes, body essentially equals viewport. div is *relatively* positioned (_not_ relative to body, relative to its "normal" position in the flow). p is *absolutely* positioned (explicit X and Y coordinates) relative to the div.

Comment: I put the body tag in just to make it clear that there's nothing else on the page, but I could have just as easily left it out. In fact, body is a regular element, so in the first example when I say "viewport" I mean viewport, not body. (You can put a margin on the body element and a background color on the html element if you want to.) If you _want_ to position elements relative to the body, now that you know how to change the reference element, you could easily do that by putting `body { position: relative; }` in your stylesheet. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @joelhardi - Thanks. I am slightly confused when you say that div is relative to its normal position and possibly the use of the term viewport. My understanding of viewport is the white canvas within the browser.

Comment: @joelhardi - I also take it as LaC pointed out earlier that if for example I had the div `element` set to have the position of `top: 20px;` the `p` element set to have the position of `right: 20px;`, it would inherit the top position of 20px and right position of 20px. However if I have the `div` element set to `top: 20px;` and `right: 20px` the `p` element assuming nothing had changed would inherit the top position of 20px and right position of 40px. Is that right?

Comment: You've understood viewport correctly. When I say the div is relative to its normal position in the flow, what that means is that it will be exactly where it would be if it were normally (statically) positioned, only offset. So for instance: `<p><p><p style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 5px;"><p>` is just 4 paragraphs one after the other. The third one is offset 5px to the right but it is otherwise exactly where it would be if statically positioned.

Comment: There is no "inheritance" in the OO sense. Only the reference element has changed. Relative means relative to its "normal" position. And absolute means absolute. If you do absolute positioning, `top: 20px; right: 20px;` then the element is positioned 20px below and 20px to the left of the top-right corner of the reference element. Not 40 -- there is no inheritance or cumulative aspect. LaC was explaining things a different way ... let's not confuse things more by combining examples.

Comment: @joelhardi - Thanks. Maybe the use of the term `inheritance` was incorrect however I have seen examples on various website such as http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/HTML_and_CSS/Absolute_Positioning_To_Another_Block.htm that show instances of the secondary element having combined position values of the parent e.g. 20px + 50px where 20px belongs to the parent and 50px to the child.

Comment: Yes, if you want to think of everything in terms of where it is in relation to some origin point, you can do that. That might make sense if you're nesting two absolute-position elements. But there's no actual inheritance or additive aspect. If you nest `<div style="position: absolute; left: 10px;"><div style="position: absolute; left: 10px;"></div></div>` then the first div is 10px from the origin and the second is 10px from the first, or 20px from the origin. Sounds like you've got it ... if not I suggest playing around with dummy HTML, it's not that complicated and easier to see in practice.

Answer (score 6):

Absolute positioning is relative to the nearest ancestor with absolute, relative or fixed positioning. Sometimes it's useful to give an element relative positioning just to establish a new references frame for positioning its children with absolute positioning.

Comment: @LaC - Thanks but can you simplify what you meant as I lost you at `Absolute positioning is relative to the nearest ancestor with absolute, relative or fixed positionin`

Comment: Let's say you have a div on a page. It has absolute positioning with top,left = 0,0, and all of its ancestors (that is, the elements that contain it, up to the page body) have normal positioning (not absolute, relative, or fixed). Then the div is displayed at the top left corner of the page. Now let's say you have a div absolutely positioned at 300,100, and another div inside it absolutely positioned at 50,50. Then the first div is at 300,100 relative to the page, and the second is at 50,50 relative to the first div, which means it's at 350,150 relative to the page.

Comment: @LaC - That's much clearer. I have paraphrased. Please correct me if I am wrong. The second div is positioned at 300 and 100 because the first div with the position absolute was` top: 0` and `left: 0`. The third div is positioned at 350, 150 because it is relative to its parent i.e. the second div. Now assuming I my understadind was correct, how do you decide when  to use the position aboslute and relative i.e. when do you make one a parent of the other?

Comment: @JAA149 - The reason I say third div is because LaC stated in the first line i.e. there is a div that has an absolute position of 0, 0. That would make the div with the position 300, 100 the second div and the div with the position 50, 50 the third div unless I have misunderstood the answer.

Comment: Yes, there is a relationship. And the ancestry can cover many levels, because the default setting for position is `inherit`. See also this little [example](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/qvqRn/1/).

Comment: @NGLN - Sorry. I though there were only 4 positions i.e. static, absolute, static and fixed. I would like to understand how you set the ancestry i.e. dependency of one div tag over another.

Comment: Whaaah, the default is static. ;) Are somehow inherit and static interchangable?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Modify my jsfiddle and practice with it as you want. Add an extra level, add a fixed div, etc...

Comment: @NGLN - Thanks. I'll play around with it.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: it was meant to be two different examples. In the first there is only a single div. In the second there are two divs, one nested within the other. The second of these two is at 50,50 within the first, which is at 300,100 within the page.

Comment: @LaC - Right. Sorry. I thought there were 3 in total.

Answer (score 3):

An absolutely positioned element is always positioned in relative to it closet positioned ancestor. If no such ancestor exists, it will be positioned to the viewport which may or maynot be the root element "html" depending on the user agent/browser. An parent is necessirly an ancestor but an ancestor is not necessirly a parent. A child is necessirly an decendant but an decendant is not necessirly a child. Elements with the position absolute may be the children or decendants of the parent which is positioned relative. If they are, they can be positioned in relative to the position of the parent which alreday has a position of either relative or absolute. Oh forget it. Read this

[Positioning](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/)

Comment: Thanks but that is very confusing example. For me anyway.

Comment: Yeah I was once too. Lost a few hairs to really understand it. The above link it really good though!

Comment: Hopefully I don't lose any hair over it. Did have a look at the link however am finding it hard to understand when you make say an absolute position a parent of a relative position and vice versa?

Comment: Ok.Listen. Say you have the h1 element and you want to place a small image in the upper right corner of that h1 element. So you have something like "<h1>This is level 1 Heading <img src="small_image.png" /> </h1>". So now "h1" is the parent and "<img />" is the child. Without any positioning they will apear as the appear in the html markup ie., "h1" will be first and "<img />" will be second, from top to bottom. Now if you give "h1" position: absolute and "<img />" position relative with the offset properties as "right: 0; top: 0;" than the "<img />" will apear in the top right.